# Jest unit test for moment specific format

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, momentjs

I am new in jest need your help

```
 const DATE_FORMAT = 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss';
 const DEFAULT_FORMAT = 'MM-DD-YYYY';
 const OUT_TIME_HOUR =23;
 const OUT_TIME_MIN = 0;
 const OUT_TIME_SEC= 0;

export const getTime= (status: boolean): string => {
const date: any = new Date();
let resetDate: string;
if (status) {
 date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1);
 resetDate = moment(date, DEFAULT_FORMAT)
  .utc()
  .set({ h: OUT_TIME_HOUR , m: OUT_TIME_MIN , s: OUT_TIME_SEC})
  .format(DATE_FORMAT);
 } else {
  resetDate= moment(date, DEFAULT_FORMAT)
  .utc()
  .set({ h: OUT_TIME_HOUR , m: OUT_TIME_MIN , s: OUT_TIME_SEC})
   .format(DATE_FORMAT);
}
return resetDate;
};
```

I want to write test case in jest form above function like if status is false then should return todayDate with 23 hr `2021-01-12 23:00:00` and if status is true then should return nextDay  `2021-01-13 23:00:00`

How to mock moment specific time can anyone help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to spy `global.Date` object, and mock some new date, something like:

```
import { getTime } from 'your-path';

describe('get time', () => {
  test('should return 23:00h - today', () => {
    const mockDate = new Date(1610488800000);
    const spy = jest
     .spyOn(global, 'Date')
     .mockImplementation(() => mockDate)

    expect(getTime(false)).toEqual('2021-01-12 23:00:00');

    spy.mockRestore();
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your prompt reply not is place of static string form can we make dynamic like new Date() utc() ?